# Trancend StoreJet 25M3 USB 3.0 1TB less than a few days old and seems dead

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive

So I got an external 1TB USB 3.0 hard disk drive 3 days ago at Christmas Eve the 24th. Today it’s the 27th. I’ve been using it every single day from the 24th. Two hours ago I noticed I couldnt access something I’d put on the drive and realised the device was off. The blue LED-light was off, the device started beeping for a few seconds when I plugged it in and out.

I know other people have put up similar questions about this before but I just want an answer to my personal predicament. How is it possible that a brand new external hard drive already broke 3 days after I unpacked and plugged it in?

The cable has had no way of being damaged, I’ve been careful with it and I haven’t moved it around at all, so the cable shouldn’t be the problem. I don’t have a similar cable so I unfortunately can’t check it out. Same with the device itself, it’s been laying on my computer chassis since the day I unpacked it.

Comment: Probably not much consolation but if a drive is going to fail it is more likely to happen within the first few days of use. Once it gets past that point it will probably last a long time ... See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathtub_curve

Answer (score 0):

So let's cover some basics: 
  try a different USB port on your system (e.g. move from a 3.0 port to a 2.0)
  try a port on the front of the box instead of the back.

If it is still dead, no lights, no sounds, then like Jake noted above regarding your data, you might just have to take it back for a warranty swap.